# GROUP BY with a Formatted Date and Left Join

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble making formatted dates group properly, I am thinking it might have to do with my left join, but I am not sure the path to take. Heres my query and results. For simplicity below I have not included the additional columns but note that utilizing distinct for the select, I don't believe is an option as it throws off my calculations.

When I use this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(posts.post_date, "%Y%m%d") AS 'Date', COUNT(*) AS 'Orders'
FROM wp_posts AS posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta ON posts.ID = meta.post_id
WHERE meta.meta_key = '_order_total'
AND posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND posts.post_status = 'wc-completed'
```

I get this:

```
20170204
20170218
20170301
20170301
20170314
20170401
20170401
20170402
20170403
20170405
20170412
20170426
20170501
20170501
20170501
20170501
20170501
20170504
```

When I add the Group By, the results just drop down to a single line:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(posts.post_date, "%Y%m%d") AS 'Date'
FROM wp_posts AS posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta ON posts.ID = meta.post_id
WHERE meta.meta_key = '_order_total'
AND posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND posts.post_status = 'wc-completed'
GROUP BY 'Date'
```

I get this:

```
20170204
```

My desired output is:

```
 20170204
 20170218
 20170301
 20170314
 20170401
 20170402
 20170403
 20170405
 20170412
 20170426
 20170501
 20170504
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: great question, I will update it, one moment

Comment: Try `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(posts.post_date, "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: Perfect! That did it!

Comment: You are currently grouping by the string literal `'Date'`, which won't work.  Just repeat what you are selecting already, i.e. `DATE_FORMAT(...)`.

Comment: You can group by the alias, but you should not quote the alias to begin with... `DATE_FORMAT(...) AS Date` (unquoted or backtick quoted)  and then you can use `GROUP BY Date` (also unquoted)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql